# Translating a function from R to Python

Tags: python, r

Im trying to convert r code to python, to learn python better, and am stuck on a simple function which checks all rows 6 columns to see if all contain NA then print NA or if every row is not all NA print the max to a new column in the dataframe.

This is what I have in R:

```
my.max <- function(x) ifelse( !all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm=T), NA 
data$datemax <- apply(data[,110:116],1,my.max)
```

How can I define the equivalent function in python?

What I have done in python so far is this:

```
def my_max(x):
    if x.all().notna():
        max(x)
    else:
        'NA'

data['datemax'] = data.iloc[:,109:115].apply(my_max)
```

Comment: `NA` doesn't mean anything in python.  We use `np.nan` for null entries.

Comment: Also, judging from the Pandas documentation, you have `all()` and `notna()` backward. `notna()` returns a dataframe of Boolean values, and `all()` determines if all the values in a dataframe of Boolean values are `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you don't even need a check. Numpy will handle that for you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(some_data) # Your dataframe

def my_max(row):
    return np.max(row) # Returns np.nan if all columns are np.nan, otherwise maxima

df['new_column'] = df.apply(my_max)
```